# Why am I getting a "View-Only" file in VSCode when using "Attach" method of JS BrowserDebugging in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, visual-studio-code, terminal

Environment:

- OS: macOS Big Sur 11.5.2 (20G95)
- Chrome: Version 93.0.4577.82 (Official Build) (x86_64)
- VSCode: Version: 1.60.1
  Commit: 83bd43bc519d15e50c4272c6cf5c1479df196a4d
  Date: 2021-09-10T17:09:14.403Z (5 days ago)
  Electron: 13.1.8
  Chrome: 91.0.4472.164
  Node.js: 14.16.0
  V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
  OS: Darwin x64 20.6.0

---

### My action:

1. {**VSCode**} Open the workspace containing my project directory.
2. {**VSCode**} Add the following block to 'launch.json' in the "configurations" array:

```
{
   "type": "pwa-chrome",
   "request": "attach",
   "name": "Attach Chrome Debugging to Browser for VSCode",
   "port": 9222,
   "url": "http://localhost:8888/",
   "urlFilter": "http://localhost:8888/*",
   "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
}
```

3. {**VSCode**} Save 'launch.json'
4. {**Chrome**} Close all running instances of Chrome
5. {**Terminal**} Navigate to root (`/`)
6. {**Terminal**} Run the command: `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir=remote-debug-profile`

#### *Outcome:*

1. {**Chrome**} Application opens with a popup (not as expected):
   [image: Screenshot of popup with text reading: "Google Chrome cannot read and write to its data directory: remote-debug-profile]

---

### My action:

1. {**Chrome**} Click "Ok" button.

#### *Outcome:*

1. {**Chrome**} A window opens prompting "Who's using Chrome?" with an option to select my desired user profile as expected.

---

### My action:

1. {**Chrome**} Click on my desired user profile.

#### *Outcome:*

1. {**Chrome**} A window opens with my desired user profile logged in as expected.

---

### My action:

1. {**VSCode**} Add a breakpoint to my code via a `debugger;` statement in my HTML file.
2. {**VSCode**} Click "Run" button with my debugging profile selected.
3. {**Chrome**} Conduct behavior to trigger breakpoint in my code.

#### *Outcome:*

1. {**VSCode**} The breakpoint is triggered **HOWEVER:** it is triggered in a "read-only" version of my file, opened in a new tab separate from my actual file.

---

## My Desired Outcome

**Using "attach"** I want to be able to have the breakpoint activate inside of the actual file in VSCode, not a "Read-Only" version.

---

I've spent about two hours researching this issue and as far as I can tell it has to do with:

- The location I'm running the terminal command from. I tried:

  - Running it from the project directory, however it dumped a ton of code into my project directory **AND** failed to open an instance of Chrome where I could select my desired user profile - instead opening up a user profile agnostic Chrome window.
- The `--user-data-dir=remote-debug-profile` line in the terminal command.
- My configuration in Launch.JSON. I've tried combinations of:

  - `"type": "chrome"`
  - `"webRoot": "*/thedirectpathtomyprojectdirectory*"`
  - `"webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src"`
  - `"userDataDir": "/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Profile 1"`
  - `"userDataDir": "/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome"`
  - `"sourceMapPathOverrides": {"webpack://?:*/*": "${workspaceFolder}/*"}`
  - `"sourceMaps": true`

### *I'm at a total loss - but feel very close to the solution.*